# Is there a package for polar plot in android studio, given data set of (r,theta)?

Tags: android, android-studio, plot, polar-coordinates

From what I found most of the package return a piechart not a polar.

I have a list of data containing the radius and the angle (r,theta) and want to plot it in an android app

Does anyone know a package for this application?

Some image to make it clearer what I'm asking.

polar plot

[image]

radiation pattern

[image]

Thank you very much for your help in advance.